# Anchor link not working inside alternative tabs in accordion effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I have this tabs hiding each other with css and javascript:

```
 <div class="accordionContent">
        <div class="menusfondo">
            <div class="content">
                <ul class="tabs2">
                <li><a href="#scheda4" id="uno">INTRODUZIONE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#scheda5">FILOSOFIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#scheda6">CASI DI SUCCESSO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#scheda7">ULTIME INNOVAZIONI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#scheda8">CONTATTI</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="contenitore_tab2">
                <div id="scheda4" class="contenuto_tab2">
                    <h1>title</h1>
                    <h2>title2</h2>
                    <p>content <a href="#scheda5">link scheda 5</a>. content</p>
                </div>
                <div id="scheda5" class="contenuto_tab2">
                      <h1> title</h1>
                      <h2> title2</h2>
                    <p>content</p>
                </div>
                <div id="scheda6" class="contenuto_tab2">
                       <h1>title</h1>
                       <h2>title2 </h2>
                    <p>content</p></div>
                <div id="scheda7" class="contenuto_tab2">
                       <h1>title</h1>
                       <h2>title2</h2>
                    <p>content</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                </div>
          </div>            
    <div id="wrapper2">
    <div class="accordionButton uno"><div class="content">
    <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="hidden"></div></div>
    <div class="accordionContent ">
        <div class="menusfondo">
            <div class="content">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="#scheda1">INTRODUZIONE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#scheda2">FILOSOFIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#scheda3">NEGOZIO ONLINE</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="window.open('http://www.eurotesterpen.com/contact','_blank');">CONTATTI</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="contenitore_tab">
                <div id="scheda1" class="contenuto_tab">
```

The anchor which doesn't work is inside the div "scheda4". It is exactly like the links in the menu for each tabs but i'm not sure if i should chain it to the javascript to make it work.
The javascript is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".contenuto_tab2").hide(); //Nascondo tutti i contenuti
$("ul.tabs2 li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Attivo il primo tab
$(".contenuto_tab2:first").show(); //Mostro il primo contenuto (contenuto del primo tab)

$("ul.tabs2 li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs2 li").removeClass("active"); //Rimuovo tuttle le classi "active"
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Attivo il tab selezionato
    $(".contenuto_tab2").hide(); //Nascondo tutti i contenuti

    var tabAttivo = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Prendo il valore dell'attributo href del tab per attivare il realtivo contenuto
    $(tabAttivo).fadeIn(); //Faccio un Fade in per mostrare il contenuto dell'ID appena trovato
    return false;
});
```

});

Why doesn't it show the right tab (scheda 5) when i click on it? The effect of the click is none, the page remains the same. Please can you give me some help?

Comment: the problem is in CSS. provide a fiddle demo please.

Comment: Depends on how your CSS and Javascript works. Based on only this information, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: I've updated the question with the javascript...

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this:

```
 <div id="scheda4" class="contenuto_tab2">
                <h1>title</h1>
                <h2>title2</h2>
                <p class="link">content <a href="#scheda5">link scheda 5</a>. content</p>
            </div>
```

then in the javascript, inside the document-ready function:

```
 $("p.link").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs2 li").removeClass("active"); //Rimuovo tuttle le classi "active"
    $('ul.tabs2 li a[href="#scheda5"]').addClass("active"); //Attivo il tab selezionato
    $(".contenuto_tab2").hide(); //Nascondo tutti i contenuti

    var tabAttivo = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Prendo il valore dell'attributo href del tab per attivare il realtivo contenuto
    $(tabAttivo).fadeIn(); //Faccio un Fade in per mostrare il contenuto dell'ID appena trovato
    return false;
});
```

It actually works except for this line:

```
 $('ul.tabs2 li a[href="#scheda5"]').addClass("active"); //Attivo il tab selezionato
```

But i didn't really get why....